# Почему программа не выводит минимальное и максимальное значение массива и не сортирует его по возрастанию?

Tags: c++

Расскажите, пожалуйста, почему программа не выводит минимальное и максимальное значение массива и не сортирует его по возрастанию?

```
Таск:
Написать функцию, определяющую в двумерном массиве целых чисел :
  Сумму всех элементов массива;
  Среднее арифметическое всех элементов массива;
  Минимальный элемент;
  Максимальный элемент.
```

Написать функцию для сортировки элементов двухмерного масива по возрастанию.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Fill_Random_Numbers
(int matrix[][50], const size_t rows, const size_t columns)
{
    srand(time(0)); 

    for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (size_t column = 0; column < columns; column++)
        {
            matrix[row][column] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }
}


void Print(int matrix[][50], const size_t rows, const size_t columns)
{
    for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        cout << endl;
        for (size_t column = 0; column < columns; column++)
        {
            cout << matrix[row][column] << " ";   
        }
    }
}

int Sum(int matrix[][50], const size_t rows, const size_t columns)
{
    int sum = 0; 
    for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (size_t column = 0; column < columns; column++)
        {
            sum += matrix[row][column];
        }
    }
    return sum; 
}

double  Average( int add[][50], size_t rows, size_t columns)
{
    int numbersElements = rows * columns;
    
    double sum = Sum(add, rows, columns);
  
    return sum / numbersElements;
}

int Max_Min
(int add[][50], size_t rows, size_t columns,
    size_t min_i, size_t min_j, size_t max_i, size_t max_j)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            if (add[min_i][min_j] > add[i][j])
            {
                min_i = i;
                min_j = j;
            }
            if (add[max_i][max_j] < add[i][j])
            {
                max_i = i;
                max_j = j;
            }
        }
    }
    return max_i, max_j, min_i, min_j;
}

void Sort_Array
(int matrix [][50], size_t row, size_t col)
{
    for (int iteration = 0; iteration <= (row * col); iteration++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < col - 1; j++)
            {
                if (matrix[i][j] > matrix[i][j + 1])
                {
                    int temp = matrix[i][j];
                    matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j + 1];
                    matrix[i][j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < col; x++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < row - 1; z++)
            {
                if (matrix[z][x] > matrix[z][x + 1])
                {
                    int temp = matrix[z][x];
                    matrix[z][x] = matrix[z][x + 1];
                    matrix[z][x + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void Print_Sort_Array(int matrix[][50], size_t row, size_t col)
{
    cout << "Sort : \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
      cout << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            cout << matrix[i][j] << "\t";
        }
    }
}



int main()
{

    const int rows = 50, columns = 50;
    int row, col;
    cout << "Enter the number of rows of the matrix:";
    cin >> row;
    cout << "Enter the number of columns in the matrix:";
    cin >> col;
    int matrix  [rows][columns];
    Fill_Random_Numbers(matrix, row, col);
    cout << "\nMatrix:\n";
    Print(matrix, row, col);

    cout << "\nSum of all elements of the matrix: " 
         << Sum(matrix, row, col) << endl;

    float average;
    cout << "\nAverage of all elements of the matrix: "
        << Average(matrix, row, col) << endl;

    int max_i = 0, max_j = 0;
    int min_i = 0, min_j = 0;
    Max_Min(matrix, min_i, min_j, max_i, max_j);
    cout << "Min element indexes: " << min_i << ", " << min_j << endl;
    cout << "Max element indexes: " << max_i << ", " << max_j << endl;
    
    Sort_Array(matrix, row, col);
    Print_Sort_Array(matrix, row, col);

        return 0;   
}
```

Comment: 1) Вы вроде бы нигде не вызываете функцию `Sort_Array`, поэтому и не сортирует матрицу. 2) Чтобы функция `Max_Min` изменила значения переменных `min_i` и т.д. передавайте их в функцию либо по ссылке, либо по указателю. С минимальными изменениями имеющегося кода — это передавать по ссылке: `int Max_Min (..., size_t& min_i, size_t& min_j, ...)`. 3) `return max_i, max_j, min_i, min_j;` — это так не работает. Точнее работает, но не так как вы думаете. Ключевые слова — оператор запятая.

Comment: спасибо wololo.

Comment: Челенж в том что нужно сделать без указателей и ссылок. на максимальное изменение имеющегося кода покорно согласен.

Comment: Да, теперь с вызовом Sort_Array(matrix, row, col); в главной функции пошла сортировка, но В первом СТОЛБЦЕ ВЫДАЕТ -858993460